# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. visual basic 2015

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting this error, this started when I created a new form
I'm using Visual Basic 2015

```
Public Class Form2
    Private MARKSDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Private MARKSCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder
    Private MARKSDataTable As New DataTable
    Private MARKSConnection As New SqlConnection
    Private MyRowPosition As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MARKSConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=c:\users\jonn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SMART\SMART\SMART.mdf; Integrated Security=True"
    MARKSConnection.Open()

End Sub

Private Sub comMkSubj_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comMkSubj.TextChanged

    MARKSDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Students", MARKSConnection)
    MARKSCmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(MARKSDataAdapter)
    MARKSDataAdapter.Fill(MARKSDataTable)

    Dim i, n As Integer
    n = MARKSDataTable.Rows.Count
    Dim y As Integer = 5

    For i = 1 To n Step 1
        Dim NewLabel As New Label
        Dim NewTxt As New TextBox

        NewLabel.Name = "Label" & i
        NewLabel.AutoSize = True
        NewLabel.Text = MARKSDataTable.Rows(MyRowPosition)("Name")
        NewLabel.Location = New Point(0, y)

        NewTxt.Name = "Txt" & i
        NewTxt.Size = New Size(50, 20)
        NewTxt.Location = New Point(170, y - 3)
        NewTxt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center

        mkPanel.Controls.Add(NewTxt)
        mkPanel.Controls.Add(NewLabel)

        MyRowPosition += 1
        y += 35
    Next

    LabelHeading.Text = comMkClass.Text + " " + comMkTerm.Text + ",  " + txtMkYear.Text + ": " + comMkSubj.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

In form 1, the connection of the same syntax works fine
But when I move to form 2, it doesn't load
It gives me this error at `MARKSDataAdapter.Fill(MARKSDataTable)`

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: Is this in Visual Basic (`[vb]`) or Visiual basic for applications (`[vba]`). The first is "stand-alone" the latter an implementation of VB in various office applications.

Comment: It is a stand-alone, connected to an mdf database

Comment: Then please retag your question acoordingly. You can find an edit button on the bottom left of your question.

Comment: in which line did you get error?

Comment: Line 3
"MARKSDataAdapter.Fill(MARKSDataTable)"

Comment: I wonder why we are told about an error involving the `ConnectionString` property but we don't get to see anything about `MarksConnection.` How does the connection string look. Where does it reside? Does it even exist? I mean after all, this error can come from something line `Dim MARKSConnection As New OleDbConnection()`

Comment: Where are the lines `Dim MarksConnection As New SQLConnection()` and `MarksConnection.ConnectionString =` ? Or something like that?

Comment: @CharlesMay
Private MARKSDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Private MARKSCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder
    Private MARKSDataTable As New DataTable
    Private MARKSConnection As New SqlConnection
    Private MyRowPosition As Integer = 0

Comment: But what does the connection string look like? To form a proper connection you should have something like:`Private MARKSConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDBName;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")` If you only have what you commented with then you need to take a look at [This site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for help with connecting to your database.

Comment: @CharlesMay My connection is
'MARKSConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=c:\users\jonn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SMART\SMART\SMART.mdf; Integrated Security=True"        MARKSConnection.Open()'

Comment: OK, can you edit your post and include that code and where it's located?

Comment: Led me try that

Comment: I don't see why that would cause the error. Is it possible you're doing something in another method with the connectionstring? You have it defined global to the class so anywhere else that does something with it will affect this code.

Comment: @CharlesMay That is the entire code in form 2
I used the same syntax in form 1 and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes

Instead of creating new instances in the form's scope, just declare the variable

so instead of:

```
Private MARKSConnection As New SqlConnection
```

just do

```
Private MARKSConnection As SqlConnection
```

Then right before you instantiate the dataadapter let's try

```
MARKSConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=c:\users\jonn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SMART\SMART\SMART.mdf; Integrated Security=True")
```

Then remark out both lines in the form load. The DataAdapter handles Opening and closing the connection so that `MARKSConnection.Open()` isn't needed in this case.